# php cron jobs from cpanel is not working. No error in email

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have uploaded a simple cron.php with insert in mySQL database.

cron.php

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --user=[myUsernameToDatabase] --password=[myPasswordToDatabase] --database=[myDatabaseName] --execute="INSERT INTO room (room_name,room_guid) VALUES ('test', 'testing')"
```

I have added this in cpanel -> Cron Jobs

Common Settings: one minute

Command: `/usr/bin/php -q /home/myUsername/public_html/cron.php`

I receive email every minute with the code I added in cron jobs -> Command and no error. But nothing is added in my database.

My test query works fine if I run it in my database

```
INSERT INTO room (room_name,room_guid) VALUES ('test', 'testar')
```

Comment: That's a `bash` script you're using, not `PHP`.

Comment: I have also tested to write the script in cron jobs -> command but I receive error. Or how do I use it? I am on a shared hosting with cpanel.

Comment: can you see any error output?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run a `bash` shell script as `PHP`, which simply won't work. There are a few things you need to do before this can even have a chance of executing successfully:

```
1. Rename cron.php to cron.sh

2. DO NOT put the script in your `public_html` directory. 
   locate it somewhere not public (eg. /home/myUsername/scripts/).

3. Try using this in your crontab:
   /bin/sh /home/myUsername/scripts/cron.sh 2>&1
```

At the very least this should get things in a better position to work properly.

Comment: Thanks. I get this error in the email: syntax error near unexpected token `('. I have '(' in my database password. E.g password "24m(J23".

Comment: try to put the password in single tick '

Comment: If I put password in ' ' I get the error "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '[myUser]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"